# Delete empty topics from Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka

I would like to delete all empty Kafka topics (periodically from cron). I have been unable to find one command to do this in the documentation? Moving onto scripting:

Firstly I have set `delete.topic.enable=true`

The problem is finding the actual current number of messages in a topic. I can show the total message count with:

```
$KAFKA_DIR/bin/kafka-run-class.sh kafka.tools.GetOffsetShell \
  --broker-list $KAFKA_BOOTSTRAP --topic $TOPIC --time -1
```

However this includes messages which have expired? How do I find the actual *current* count in a topic, short of using a consumer?

Comment: You could run a *disk usage* script over each broker and sum over all partitions for a topic...

Comment: Hello. Did you find or create your own solution for this and would you consider sharing it as an answer to this question?

Comment: I resorted to searching for empty log files. The key line `find $KAFKA_LOGS/*/*.log -empty -exec dirname {} \;`
Use with care, depends on naming convention, etc.

Answer (score 0):

`kafka.tools.GetOffsetShell` will count offsets instead of actual messages.

To get all the messages stored for the topic you need to seek a consumer to the beginning and sum up the results for each partition.

Answer (score 0):

If you have ELK stack integrated with your Kafka Cluster, this task becomes considerably easy.

Step 1: Find all topics in Kafka cluster.

```
async function getKafkaTopics() {
    let total_kafka_topics = [];
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        request({
            headers: {
                'auth': KAFKA_AUTH
            },
            uri: `${KAFKA_URL}/admin/topics`,
            method: 'GET',
            json: true,
        }, function (err, res, body) {
            if (err) {
                console.log("Error encountered while getting Kafka Topics: ",err);
                reject(err);
            }
            if (body) { 
                body.forEach(function (item) { 
                    if(item && item.name)
                        total_kafka_topics.push(item.name) 
                }); 
            }
            resolve(total_kafka_topics);
        });
    })
}
```

Step 2: Try to find whether there are any hits for any topic within last 7 days:

```
async function callElasticSearch(topic) {
  console.log("Calling elastic search for topic: ",topic)
  var url = ELASTIC_SEARCH_URL + `/${INDEX}/_search?q=${topic}`
  let body = {
    "query": {
        "range": {
            "timestamp": {
                "gte": "now-7d/d",
                "lt": "now/d"
            }
        }
    }
}
var options = {
    url: url,
    headers: {
        'Authorization': ELASTIC_AUTHORIZATION
    },
    body: body, json: true
}
return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    request.get(options, function (err, res, body) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(`Error encountered while calling elastic search for topic : ${topic}`,err)
            reject(err)
        } else {
            let obj = {
                topic: topic,
                body: body
            }
            console.log("Response Recieved for: ",topic)
            resolve(obj);
        }
    });
})
}
```

You can call this function iteratively like so:

```
async function start() {
    let empty_topic = [];
    console.log("Start Time: ", new Date())
    let total_kafka_topics = await getKafkaTopics();
    console.log("Total Kafka Topics: ", total_kafka_topics.length)
    const { results, errors } = await PromisePool
        .withConcurrency(5)
        .for(total_kafka_topics)
        .process(async topic => {
            const elasticResponse = await callElasticSearch(topic)
            if (elasticResponse.body && elasticResponse.body.hits && elasticResponse.body.hits.total == 0 && elasticResponse.topic) {
                empty_topic.push(elasticResponse.topic)
            }
        })
    console.log("Number of empty topics from past 7 days: ", empty_topic.length)
    console.log("Empty Topics: %j", empty_topic)
    console.log("Time Ended: ", new Date())
}
```